# How to programmatically add mailbox alias on an Exchange 2007 server from C# web app?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, alias, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

As the subject says, I have a C# web application (.NET 3.5) that's communicating with an Exchange 2007 server. What I need help with is to programmatically (preferably from the web app itself) add a new mailbox alias to a certain mailbox and then before sending out the mail set the new alias as the reply-to address.

I'm fairly new to scripting, but from what I've read so far, most people seem to be suggesting the Exchange Powershell to accomplish this. Any hints towards a third-part API that would solve this would be appreciated. I've looked at the EWS API but from what I've seen so far it doesn't look like that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with EWS API. What you need is New-Mailbox PowerShell command.

If you have PowerShell v2 installed, you can call it remotely, read about PowerShell Remoting.

Answer (score -2):

You can use "managed code" to do this.  Essentially, you are programmatically communicating with Powershell.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332449%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

This, and other sources which you can find via Google, should help you write c# code to perform Powershell tasks.